# Filter array with another array

Tags: javascript, array

I want to output only the roles that contain the same group as the user.

```js
// User can be part of many groups
const user = {
  groups: ["group2"]
};

// Roles can have many groups
// What you see here is the output or 2 different data source
// Thats why we have group duplication inside different role
const roles = [{
  name: "role1",
  groups: [{
    id: "group1"
  }]
}, {
  name: "role2",
  groups: [{
    id: "group1"
  }, {
    id: "group2"
  }]
}];

const result = roles.filter(role => role.groups.filter(group => user.groups.indexOf(group.id) > -1).length)
console.log(result);
```

**Is there a better way by using reduce or something else?**

Comment: Perhaps `roles.filter(role => role.groups.find(group => user.groups.includes(group.id)))`

Comment: Also you have defined `const roles` and then you try to redefine it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is little neater IMO.

```js
// User can be part of many groups
const user = {
  groups: ["group2"]
};

// Roles can have many groups
// What you see here is the output or 2 different data source
// Thats why we have group duplication inside different role
const roles = [{
  name: "role1",
  groups: [{
    id: "group1"
  }]
}, {
  name: "role2",
  groups: [{
    id: "group1"
  }, {
    id: "group2"
  }]
}];

const result = roles.filter(role => role.groups.find(group => user.groups.includes(group.id)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` method runs a given `function` on every `item` in the `array` and returns an array of all items for which the function returns `true`. This will help us to get each sub-array of the `mainArray`.

```js
let mainArray = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f']
];

// Extract sub-arrays with filter
let temp = mainArray.filter(function(item, index, array){
        return array;
});
console.log({temp});
```

Now, we need to compare **every** sub-array with the `subArray`. For this we will use the `every` method. This method always return a boolean value `true` or `false`. That is base on the given `function` on every item in the array and returns `true`. If that `function` returns true for every true; what's that mean? Well, this mean `every` will return `false`, unless every item return `true`.

```js
let searchArray = ['c', 'd'];

// Extract every letter from the sub-array 
temp = searchArray.every(function(item, index, array){
  console.log({item});
  return true;
});
console.log({temp});
```

Finally, `includes` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.`

```js
let searchArray = ['c', 'd'];


// Compare a letter in the searchArray.
let tempItem = 'c';
temp = searchArray.includes(tempItem);
console.log({temp});
```

Now, we can combine all and replace `functions` with the [Arrow Function Syntax](https://codeburst.io/javascript-understand-arrow-function-syntax-ab4081bba85b). And happy coding.

```js
let mainArray = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f']
];
let searchArray = ['c', 'd'];

// All together
let results = mainArray.filter(array => array.every(item => searchArray.includes(item)));
console.log({results});
```